# Как написать подобное окно для ввода текста,в котором как в ворде можно будет выбирать тип шрифта

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На подобии вот этого,можно ли это написать на чистом js или нужно использовать что то большее?

Comment: tiny mce и много других готовых редакторов

Answer (score 1):

Вот как это работает под капотом:

Мы создаем `div`, который имитирует поле ввода. Это всего лишь див, но теперь у нас есть возможность вставлять в него теги типа `<u>` или `<b>`. Это псевдо-поле для ввода будет видимо для пользователя.

Также мы создаем `textarea`, который должен быть скрыт от пользователя (в моем примере он не скрыт для наглядности). Каждый раз при клике на зеркало мы фокусируемся на этом поле и весь текст отсюда переходит в зеркало.

Теперь при клике на кнопки мы смотрим какая кнопка была нажата и в зависимости от нее добавляем в наш `textarea` нужный нам тег, который потом при вставке в зеркало как HTML код автоматически будет распарсен браузером.

Код чисто для демонстрации и нуждается в доработках, а лучше, для таких сложных задач не изобретать велосипеды ;)

```js
let mirror = document.getElementById("mirror"),
  actual = document.getElementById("actual"),
  buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

mirror.addEventListener("click", e => {
  mirror.classList.add("active");
  actual.focus();
});

actual.addEventListener("input", e => {
  let value = e.data;
  if (value) {
    mirror.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.value;
  }
});

Array.from(buttons).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let element = e.currentTarget;
    switch (element.getAttribute("data-style")) {
      case "bold":
        actual.value = actual.value + "<b></b>";
        break;
      case "italic":
        actual.value = actual.value + "<i></i>";
        break;
      case "underline":
        actual.value = actual.value + "<u></u>";
        break;
    }
    actual.focus();
    actual.setSelectionRange(actual.value.length - 4, actual.value.length - 4);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#actual {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 30px;
}

#mirror {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 30px;
  cursor: text;
}

#mirror.active:after {
  content: "|";
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button data-style="italic">Курсив</button>
<button data-style="bold">Жирный</button>
<button data-style="underline">Подчеркнутый</button>

<br>Наше зеркало для ввода. Сюда нужно начать вводить текст.
<div id="mirror"></div>
Куда мы вводим текст на самом деле. Сюда нужно просто смотреть, но в конечном итоге вообще скрыть это поле от глаз.
<textarea id="actual"></textarea>
```

Comment: а есть какие-то готовые решения ? я просто ничего не нашел подобного.

Comment: @Woodss48 [letmegooglethat](http://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=html+editor+js+plugin)